# Java parse File-path with different working directory

Tags: java, file, io

I have a file which contain several paths, like `.` (relative) or `/Users/...../` (absolut). I need to parse the paths that are relative to the directory of the file that contains the paths and not the working-directory and create correct File-instances. I can not change the working directory of the Java-Program, since this would alter the behaviour of other components and i also have to parse several files. I don't think `public File(String parent, String child)`does what i want, but i may be wrong. The documentation is quite confusing.

Example:

```
file xy located under /system/exampleProgram/config.config has the following content:
.
/Users/Name/file
./extensions

i want to resolve these to:
/system/exampleProgram/
/Users/Name/file
/system/exampleProgram/file/
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing as well... What are you trying to do exactly? Transform relative paths into absolute paths? But are the relative paths correct? In that they are relative to the current working path or are they only relative to the current file?

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. The solution may be to not use files at all, but rather resources, but who knows based on what you've posted so far.

Comment: i can't change the file-format, i have to work with whats given to me.

Comment: @NadiaCerezo this may be stupid, but i don't understand whats confusing. What do you mean with correct? I have paths that are relative to the File (or not if they are absolute). I have tow work with them and therefore need the correct File instances.

Comment: re, `"i can't change the file-forma"` -- but you **can** improve this question. Give more clear detail on the problem please.

Comment: @Leander what I mean by "correct relative paths" are paths relative to the current working path. What sometimes happens, unfortunately, is that file contains paths that are relative to themselves and that has nothing to do with the working path (the path currently used by your JVM). I surmise that this is the problem you are faced with?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels better?

Comment: @NadiaCerezo no, this is not what i want. I can't just create Files via new File(xy) since they are not relative to the working-directory. I also can't change the working-directory to the location they are relative to, this would alter the behaviour of other components. I have edited the question, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am going to assume that you have access to the path of the file you opened (either via `File.getAbsolutePath()` if it was a File descriptor or via a regex or something)...

Then to translate your relative paths into absolute paths, you can create new File descriptions with your opened file, like so:

```
File f = new File(myOpenedFilePath);
File g = new File(f, "./extensions");
String absolutePath = g.getCanonicalPath();
```

When you create a file with a `File` object and a `String`, Java treats the `String` as a path relative to the `File` given as a first argument. `getCanonicalPath` will get rid of all the redundant `.` and `..` and such.

Edit: as Leander explained in the comments, the best way to determine whether the path is relative or not (and thus whether it should be transformed or not) is to use `file.isAbsolute()`.

Comment: i would not check for `/`, since it is not portable, there is `file.isAbsolute()`.

Comment: You are completely right. I had completely forgotten about that method... My bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you probably want something like

```
    File fileContainingPaths = new File(pathToFileContainingPaths);
    String directoryOfFileContainingPaths =
    fileContainingPaths.getCanonicalFile().getParent();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileContainingPaths));
    String path;
    while ((path = r.readLine()) != null) {
       if (path.startsWith(File.separator)) {
          System.out.println(path);
       } else {
          System.out.println(directoryOfFileContainingPaths + File.separator + path);
       }
    }       
    r.close();
```

Don't forget the `getCanonicalFile()`. (You might also consider using `getAbsoluteFile()`).